# return a Tuple from minimal API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, tuples, minimal-apis

I'm trying to return a Tuple in a minimal API, it boils down to this:

```
app.MapPost("/colorkeyrect", () => server.ColorkeyRect());

public (int x, int y, int w, int h) ColorkeyRect()
{
  return (10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

But the data that is sent over the wire is an empty json:

```
content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

> '{}'

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(int, int, int, int)>(content);
```

So this becomes (0, 0, 0, 0) instead of (10, 10, 10, 10).

Is it even possible to return a Tuple in a Minimal API app?
What to do to get a valid object returned when only relying on primitive types?

Comment: The default json serialiser ignores fields, and only serialises properties. You could probably return an anonymous type instead, since tuples don't really have property names..

Comment: What would be the benefit of a `Tuple<T,T1,T2,T3>` over an actual DTO?

Comment: To me, it sounds like you should return an actual DTO. This helps with readability and can help avoid confusion. I had to think for at least 10s to figure out that your object is a rectangle and not something else.

Comment: the benefit is that a client does not need more classes and only relies on primitive types

Comment: @Fildor `ValueTuple<...>`, not `Tuple<...>` =)

Comment: @GuruStron Ok, "anything _but_ a DTO over a DTO"? :D

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen I would argue that there is no much benefit here. If client does not want to deserialize to some class - `Dictionary<string, int>` always can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. By default System.Text.Json does not serialize fields, and value tuple elements are fields ([`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2.item1?view=net-7.0)), so you need to configure `JsonOptions` (be sure to use "correct" ones - for Minimal APIs from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json` namespace):

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options => options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true);
```

But I would argue that it is a bit useless, value tuple names is a piece of information which is not represented at runtime so you will get response like:

```json
{"item1":1,"item2":2}
```

I would recommend to use either anonymous type or just create a [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) (`record struct` if really needed), it is very easy to create a new DTO type nowadays. And with target-typed new expressions it is not a big change in the method also:

```cs
record Responce(int X, int Y, int W, int H); // or record struct Responce ...

public Responce ColorkeyRect()
{
    return new (10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: @Fildor yes. Just wanted to "mimic" authors naming.

Comment: thanks a lot. My clients must be used from NET48 also so cant use record but this helps a lot